# How do I position buttons in a specific grid in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I am new to react native. I was Trying to place some buttons on my home screen. Suppose I have 6 buttons, I need the to be placed in a grid in lower half of the home screen. Something like this:

```
[ a ]  [ b ]
[ c ]  [ d ] 
[ e ]  [ f ]
```

I know we will use Flex in this and so far I have managed to put two buttons in row. Following is my code. ( I am only posting the relevant code)

```
<View style = { styles.allButtons }>
                        <View style = { styles.homeButtons }  > 
                            <Button style = { styles.buttonText }
                                color = "#157fd3"           
                                title = 'Button 1'
                                onPress = {() => { Alert.alert("Pressed"); }}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style = { styles.homeButtons }  > 
                            <Button style = { styles.buttonText }
                                color = "#157fd3"           
                                title = 'My feeds'
                                onPress = {() => { Alert.alert("to be Updated."); }}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
```

And my stylesheet looks something like this.

```
allButtons: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        margin: 5,

    },
    homeButtons: {
        flex: 1,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: 'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 45,
        width: 260,
        marginBottom: 3,
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18,
    },
```

This is producing 2 buttons in row. But if I add another button, it gets placed in the same row i;e 3 buttons in row. Help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your `allButtons` style

You may need to give your `homeButtons` container a `flex-basis: 50%` as well. Be careful because `flex-basis` doesn't account for margins.